# need to click link in navbar, pass it to hidden form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm not at all a programmer; I can muddle through modifying the odd file by copying examples I see, by deciphering loosely what's going on, but if you said "go program this bit," I wouldn't have the slightest clue how.  So, I'm hoping someone can give me a hand with this :)

I have a PHP file that has a navbar containing the days of the week.  I need to set it up so that when a user clicks on a day of the week in the navbar, the "ddate" form variable is set to that day, and the hidden form is then submitted.

Here's what I've got so far--some of the code is from what was pre-existing code:

```
<div class="day-input-form">
        <form action="<?php ?>" method="post" name="dayform">
            <input type="hidden" name="ddate" id="ddate" size="11" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo JText::_( "SELECTINPT" ); ?>" />
            <?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div id="navcontainer">

    <ul id="navlist">
    <?php if($currentday=="Monday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Monday">Monday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Tuesday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Tuesday">Tuesday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Wednesday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Wednesday">Wednesday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Thursday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Thursday">Thursday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Friday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Friday">Friday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Saturday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Saturday">Saturday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Sunday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#Sunday">Sunday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me a shove in the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated.  Bear in mind that, as I said, I'm no programmer, but am just making a valiant try to understand all this :)

Comment: why a form at all and not just a link? .. file.php?day=Monday ..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (I'm using jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navcontainer").find("a").click(function() {
        var form = $("form[name='dayform']");
        form.find("input[name='ddate']").val($(this).attr("href"));
        form.submit();
    });
});​
```

Here is an example in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tFw4Q/12/

Comment: Hmmm...maybe I didn't properly explain my setup :)

Basically, here's what happens. The PHP shown above is from a file called "default.php".  Originally, there was a calendar selection box too.  The user would select a date, and the page would reload with the broadcast schedule for that date.  I want to modify it, because the DATE doesn't matter--the schedule is the same each week.  What matters is the DAY.  I also didn't want to force users to pick a specific date (month and date); I just want them to pick a day of the week.

sigh...runnning out of comment space...continued in a moment....

Comment: OK, to continue.  So there's also another PHP file called "schedule.php" that took the date, in Y-M-D format, and returns the schedule based on what shows are on the DATE that was selected...but it does so by seeing if the DAY OF THE WEEK that the show is broadcast on matches the DATE that was selected by the user.  So now I need it to return the schedule based on the DAY OF THE WEEK that the user selects, rather than the DATE the user selects.  Does that make any sense?  You can see what I'm talking about on the page...it's at http://qccr.dyndns.org:82/on-air-schedule.